# PowerShell: How to Compare and Match CSV data and Export a CSV

Tags: database, powershell, csv, file, create-table

I know its easy for you guys but I Need you Your Help. I have 2 CSV files

fileA.csv= All Files Paths on Server in column A

| column A |
| --- |
| /Volumes/../.../file1.mov |
| /Volumes/../.../file2.jpg |
| /Volumes/../.../file3.mp3 |

Exactly 200K records

FileB.csv= File Names for missing files I need to Located in Column A (File1.mov)

| column A |
| --- |
| /file2.jpg |
| /file1.mov |
| /file4.txt |
| /file3.mp3 |

What i need is to Check the file name with extension in fileB.csv and match it with correct path in fileA.csv . If a File name from fileA.csv in FileB.csv is not located it should mention that its not found.
so the output file looks like this

| ColumnA | ColumnB. |
| --- | --- |
| File1.mov | /Volumes/../.../file1.mov) |
| File2.jpg | /Volumes/../.../file2.jpg) |
| File3.mp3 | N/A |

This What i made till now

```
$org  = import-csv "fileA.csv"
$diff = import-csv "FileBcsv"

foreach($row in $org){

    $diffRow = $diff | Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.rule -eq $row.Rule}
    [pscustomobject]@{
    
       Rule  = $row.rule
       Value = $row.value
       Match = if($row.Value -eq $diffrow.Value){'Match'}else{"NoMatch:" +$row.Value+ $diffrow.Value}
    
    }   
}
$Results | Export-Csv -Path "./OutPutFile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Its still processing so i still dont know the if its gonna work or not

Comment: You should share an example of fileA.csv and an example of fileB.csv (as plain text) and how the expected outcome would look like in order to properly understand what you're looking to accomplish. You mention that you need to check file names in fileB.csv however your code is showing the use of `Get-Process`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well I tried Multiple commands but none gave the correct output

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\fileA.csv |FullJoin (Import-Csv .\fileB.csv) -on { Split-Path -Leaf $_.'Column A' } -Name A_,B_`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes its totally plain text. As for the expected outcome i wrote it in the question. above its the table

Comment: @iRon tried you Modification but i think i will have to make an if condition in the middle because it gave me this error
ForEach-Object: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: That means that your colums aren't called `Column A` as defined in your question. Please be exact in your [mcve] definition.

Comment: Are `fileA.csv` and `fileB.csv` actually [`csv` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)? Or just (headless) lists of filenames in which case you shouldn't use [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) at all but [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content): `Get-Content .\fileA.csv |FullJoin (Get-Content .\fileB.csv) -on { Split-Path -Leaf $_.Value } -Name A,B`

Comment: How would you like to handle multiple matches? Should the output only contain the first path found?